# AJAX to only fetch html of specific class

Tags: mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX for polling an sql query. I'm sure theres better ways to accomplish what i'm trying to do so if you have alternatives i'm all ears, however right now my query is stored in

this is what i'm using

```
$(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        url: location.href,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".list").html(html);
       }

    });
}, 5000);
});
```

This just updates the table with the entirety of the html, and i've tried many things ive found on here and google to modify my code to only update with .list, and i cannot get it to work.

Thanks for any input

Comment: Do you want to fetch the content of a perticular HTML element into the element which has "list" class?

Comment: @yogesh i just want to "refresh" the element ".list"

Comment: I think i am not following you correctly. Could you please elaborate what you meant by "Refresh" the element ".list"?

Comment: Do you want to fetch data from some other page in element .list on some JavaScript event?

Comment: @yogesh I have an SQL query listing a table of records which will be edited by multiple computers. If someone changes the database i am trying to have it reflected in "real time" (or in this case, 5000ms intervals) so users can see other users changes and not be working on the same record simultaneously without knowing it

Comment: Ok. To achieve this you need to create another PHP page which will return the updated records (read database and return resultset) and then using this result set you can update the ".list" element. Place the path of that PHP page in URL section on ajax request

Comment: @yogesh haha i cant believe i couldnt think of this on my own. thanks a ton

Comment: Ok. Glad to know that you got the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling javascript to request the current page by setting **url: location.href**. As a result, your function gets all the HTML of the current page and places it in **.list**.

You need to have some server side code that will run your query and return the correct content only.

[PHP - AJAX and MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)